# show first value by default in drop-down

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

i have created one drop down and i want to show the first value by default in drop down.

```
<select > 
          <option let i = index;" [selected]="i===0" >{{role.name}}</option>
          </select>
```

but this code is not working.
when I am removing, on this time I am able to see the first value by default in drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `[(ngModel)]`, if you have no value there in `roleVal`, nothing will be chosen. You can solve this by giving it the initial value:

```
roleVal = this.addwrkfrcePopUpMdl.userRole[0].name
```

which means you can remove `[selected]` altogether.

Comment: i also tried    <option selected="selected" value=''>Select</option>... but even select is not coming by default

Comment: Well it should work, I assume this is part of a form, but it should work with or without it. Please recreate the issue in a plunker, since this works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/99o8MtD9sUxQ2XsdbUq4?p=preview

Comment: @rajeevtejapuriya How did it go, did you figure out the issue with the code? :)

Comment: I have tried every solution but i am getting final result

Comment: Could you reacreate the issue in a Plunker and I'd be happy to take a look :)